# Passing only one object of a ViewModel to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Home ViewModel class which contains others class:

```
public class HomeVM
{
    public ProductSearchRequest ProductSearchRequest { get; set; }
    //Other class
    //Other class
    //Other class
}
```

My home/Index view has `@model HomeVM`, and there I have a search text input:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Product"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductSearchRequest.SearchText)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

But in my Product/Search I need to receive only ProductSearchRequest because there is other pages that uses other ViewModel but contains ProductSearchRequest.

I'm trying this:

```
public ActionResult Search(ProductSearchRequest request)
{
    var response = new ProductSearchResponse
    {
        SearchText = request.SearchText,
        Products = GetProductsByName(request.SearchText)
    };

    return View(response);
}
```

but it doesn't work.. request.SearchText is always null..

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried passing in `HomeVM` to the action?

Comment: Yes, if I pass HomeVM it works, but the problem is that I have other viewModels which request Product/Search too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a stab in the dark, but your action, try calling the parameter 'ProductSearchRequest'

Or how about putting your whole form in a view for that action I.e. 'Search' that takes the 'ProductSearchRequest' as model?

Comment: Amazing !! it works !! I just changed the name of parameter to 'ProductSearchRequest' as you said. Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. However, if this form gets used all over, I'd still be inclined to create a separate view for it

Comment: Oh no, it goes in Action by the final result is: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MVC3.ViewModel.ProductSearchResponse', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MVC3.ViewModel.HomeVM'.

Comment: Did you try creating a 'ProductSearchRequest view, that takes ProductSearchRequest as model, and call the action from your home view?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is because `TextBoxFor()` will create an html input using a naming convention that is expected to be bound to the same type of model `HomeVM` as the original action.

You can try using the simple `TextBox()` helper method like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchText", Model.ProductSearchRequest.SearchText)
```

To avoid using a string value, you can make a separate form partial that takes the `ProductSearchRequest` object as the model, and call:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("SearchForm",Model.ProductSearchRequest)
```

Now you can use the `TextBoxFor()` method like this in the partial:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchRequest)
```

Comment: This should work, unless you ever change the name of the property and forget to change the magic string

Comment: Right, I was just updating for that :)

Comment: I believe that was my answer too about creating the separate view :)

Comment: Unfortunately,it doesn't work too. It goes inside ActionResult but when all is finished: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MVC3.ViewModel.ProductSearchResponse', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MVC3.ViewModel.ProductSearchRequest'.

Comment: Where is the error occurring, when binding the model to `request` or when rendering the view?  And this is for the 'Search' action, right?

Comment: @PinnyM It's occurring in the .cshtml after to leave ActionResult and doing the razor code in PartialView:     @{Html.RenderPartial("SearchText");}